# What variable type to use for parameter LPVOID lpBuffer in C++ functions WriteFile and ReadFile

Tags: c++, serial-port, microcontroller

What variable type should be used for **lpBuffer** of C++ `ReadFile` and `WriteFile` functions to communicate between a Windows XP based PC and a micro-controller based system? The PC has WinForm application in VS2010 C++/CLI. The micro-controller firmware is ANSI C.

My PC is supposed to transmit command characters (say 'S', 'C' etc) followed by command termination character `0xd` (hex for decimal 13). The micro-controller based system would respond with 5 to 10 bytes that would be mix of ASCII characters and hex numbers e.g. 'V' followed by `0x41` `0x72` etc.

**PC transmits and micro-controller receives:**

1. `TxMessage`, `PP1` and `pTx` declared as `char` and keeping `nNumberOfBytesToWrite` as 2, makes the micro-controller receive `0x53` for 'S' followed by `0xC3` instead of `0xd`.
2. `TxMessage`, `PP1` and `pTx` declared as `wchar_t` and keeping `nNumberOfBytesToWrite` as 2, makes the micro-controller receive `0x53` for 'S' only.
3. `TxMessage`, `PP1` and `pTx` declared as `wchar_t` and keeping `nNumberOfBytesToWrite` as 4, makes the micro-controller receive `0x53` for 'S' followed by `0xd` correctly.

The third scheme of transmit and receive above meets my expected behavior of a solution. But the confusion is here: Although the PC might be transmitting 4 bytes (for two `wchar` types), the micro-controller receives 2 bytes `0x53` for 'S', correctly followed by `0xD`.

**Micro-controller transmits and PC receives:**

Assuming that `wchar_t` is the right choice for `lpBuffer`, **what should be my `nNumberOfBytesToRead`** for receiving 10 bytes from the micro-controller? ReadFile would expect 20 bytes by virtue of `wchar_t`, whereas the micro-controller would transmit 10 bytes only.

Amazingly, irrespective of declaring (`RxMessage`, `PP2` and `pRx`) as `wchar_t`, `char` or `unsigned char`, ReadFile receives 10 bytes from the micro-controller (meets my expected behavior of a solution). But the issue is that transmitting 'A' 10 times from the micro-controller, ReadFile on the PC's end receives junk like 'S', `0x0`, `0xd`, `0x54`, `0x29`.

```
/// Required designer variable.
HANDLE hCommPort;
BOOL fSuccess;
array<wchar_t> ^ TxMessage;
array<unsigned char> ^ RxMessage;

TxMessage = gcnew array<wchar_t> (12);
RxMessage = gcnew array<unsigned char> (12);


{
TxMessage[0]='S';//target cmd
TxMessage[1]=0xd;//cmd termination character
DWORD dwhandled;
if (hCommPort != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
{
 pin_ptr<wchar_t> pp1 = &TxMessage[0];
 wchar_t *pTx = pp1;
 fSuccess = WriteFile(hCommPort, pTx, 4, &dwhandled, NULL);


 PurgeComm(hCommPort, PURGE_RXABORT|PURGE_TXABORT|PURGE_RXCLEAR|PURGE_TXCLEAR);

 pin_ptr<unsigned char> pp2 = &RxMessage[0];
 unsigned char *pRx = pp2;
 fSuccess = ReadFile(hCommPort, pRx, 10, &dwhandled, NULL);

}//if IsOpen
else{
 this->toolStripStatusLabel4->Text="Port Not Opened";}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apologies for not able to respond earlier than this. Infact the problem was identified and corrected after posting of my last comment. It related to 9bit protocol being forced by micro-controller. Original micro-firmware is 9bit protocol to address one of many slaves. For development-testing, i had temporary modification to 8bit protocol. Unfortunately, modifications missed the UART mode register that remained as 9bit mode. With boxed/biased mind i kept debugging

Answer (score 1):

`ReadFile/WriteFile` do not care about C++ types, they operate in terms of bytes read/written. `ReadFile` reads specified number of bytes (or less if there is less bytes to read) from file/device, and puts them into memory pointed by `lpBuffer`. `WriteFile` writes specified number of bytes to file/device from memory pointed to by `lpcBuffer`. The memory buffer for these functions is simply a region of allocated memory that has the size at least as many bytes as you tell those functions in the third parameter.

`wchat_t` is a multibyte type. It's size can be bigger than one byte. Consequently, your `TxMessage[0]='S'; TxMessage[1]=0xd;` can be actually filling not two bytes in memory, but, say, 4 bytes. For example, it can be `x0053` , `x000D` in `wchar_t` representation. From the point of view of `WriteFile` it does not care how and what you put into that memory. It will read raw memory and will write to device. So, if your device expects `x530D`, it might not be getting it, but `x0053`.

Overall, think about bytes. If you need to write 4 bytes `x0A0B0C0D` to your device, it does not matter HOW you allocated buffer for this value. It can be 4-byte `unsigned int = x0A0B0C0D`, it can be `char[ 4 ] = {x0A, x0B, x0C, x0D}`, it can be `int short [ 2 ]= {x0A0B, x0C0D}`, it can be ANY C++ type, including custom class. But the first 4 bytes of memory pointed by the memory pointer passed to `WriteFile` should be `x0A0B0C0D`.

Similarly, `ReadFile` will read number of bytes you specify. If your device sends you, say, 2 bytes, `ReadFile` will write 2 bytes it gets into memory pointed by the pointer you pass to it (and it's your responsibility to ensure it has enough bytes allocated). Again, it does not care how you allocated it as long as there are 2 bytes allocated. After that, again, you can look at these two bytes as you want - it can be `char[ 2 ]`, can be `int short` etc.

Comment: Fully agree with you @Petr, **but the fact remains, Amazingly though**; inspite of TxMessage = gcnew array<wchar_t> { 'S', '\r' }, and nNumberOfBytesToWrite as 4, micro-controller receives **TWO** bytes only that too 0x53 followed by 0xD. Making nNumberOfBytesToWrite as 2, micro-controller receives **ONE** byte only that too 0x53.

Comment: @Rich I would start by examining first 4 **bytes** of `TxMessage`. Could it be that `sizeof(wchar_t)==2` indeed, you are sending `x0053000D` and controller protocol just _ignores_ `x00`'s? Because then it will also explain that when you send 2 bytes of `TxMessage` which are `x0053`, controller gets `x53` ignoring `x00`. What if you make `char TxMessage[ 2 ] = {x53, x0D}` and send 2 bytes?

Comment: Just read your comment to Hans's answer. It seems to me you should verify the protocol used by the controller. Can you add the description from controller manual to the OP? I have a suspicion controller actually expects array of two-bytes values, not array of bytes. Can that be the case?

Comment: WinXP app and Controller firmware being debugged simultaneously with BreakPoints in respective IDEs. Controller firmware receives bytes in Rx buffer on Rx-Interrupts, irrespective of byte-values.  The firmware breaks, when either 0xd is received or timeout of 8 secs. When TxMessage type is wchar_t, Firmware breaks immediately on receipt of 2nd byte as 0xd. Post break, Rx buffer is observed to be holding TWO bytes 0x53 and 0xD. When TxMessage is Non-wchar, firmware loop breaks only after timeout of 8 secs and Post break, Rx buffer is observed to be holding TWO bytes 0x53 followed by 0x43

Comment: **Meanwhile few facts**, the serial communication is being done on virtual COM port, COM15 of FT232R. Though Tx part from PC meets operational expectations with TxMessage<wchar>, but, RxMessage <wchar_t OR char OR unsigned char> ReadFile breaks **correctly** with expected nNumberOfBytesToRead from the micro-controller (meets my expected behavior of a solution). **But the issue is that transmitting 'A' 10 times from the micro-controller, ReadFile on the PC's end receives junk like 'S', 0x0, 0xd, 0x54, 0x29**

Comment: This is not really **junk** since its beginning looks so much like what you just written to it - `x0053000D`. What are the actual number of bytes read? What do `WriteFile`, `PurgeComm` and `ReadFile` return at PC's end? How do you obtain `hCommPort`?

Comment: Actual number of bytes Read is 10 as expected in ReadFile call. WriteFile, PurgeComm and ReadFile return 0x01(true) at PC code-step-overs. Handle hCommPort obtained with 'CreateFileW(comLPCWSTR,/*L"\\\\.\\COM15"*/,GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE, 0, NULL, OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, NULL);'

Comment: Reason to consider Rx bytes as **Junk** are: Since PC-Tx part is received correctly on Micro-controller with TxMessage<wchar>, implies that hardware/software interface are established. ReadFile does NOT return until arrival of 10th byte from micro-controller. With above facts in mind; Micro-controller Transmitting all 10 bytes as 'A'; any error induced in PC-Rx (Hardware or Software) should had acted same on all 10 bytes i.e. **even if 'A' is corrupted, still 10 bytes should had remained same; be X, Y or Z**. whereas ReadFile returns all 10 bytes as different

Comment: The first bytes you receive on PC are _suspiciously_ equal to bytes which were sent by PC. It is junk in terms of it not being what you think you sent from controller. But why this junk starts with what controller just read?

Comment: Well, for FT232R does echo Tx bytes into Rx-hardware-register(or buffer). But ReadFile being called with pRx=RxMessage[0] and nNumberOfBytesToRead as 10, fresh 10 bytes are supposed to be available in RxMessage array directly from COM15. Even in worst case, assuming that echo-bytes survived and got captured in RxMessage, still trailing 8 out of 10 bytes should had been 'A' (or X,Y.Z etc for any error-source)

Comment: Most probably this Rx malfunction(problem #2) will be resolved, the moment we get answers to funny PC-Tx behavior(problem #1). Where, micro-controller receives the two characters correctly as 0x53 followed by 0xD, only when TxMessage is declared as wchar_t. Non-wchar types make the micro-controller receive the First byte correctly as 0x53 but 2nd byte wrong as 0x43. My gut feeling is both issues #1 & #2 are related and common factor being Microsoft handling of WriteFile/ReadFile function parameters

Comment: Drop CLI managed arrays. Use C++ static arrays with fixed-size types. Try writing to and reading from port just from PC end, don't startup controller. Let us know how it goes.

Comment: Well, VS2010 used to throw compile error for ReadFile and WriteFile functions saying "mixing of managed and non-managed variables not allowed" that forced me to introduce CLI managed arrays and Pin-Ptr. I can give it try once again, though !

Comment: Alas, behavior remains same even with CLI arrays replaced with local static arrays defined in the function as copy-pasted below. TxStatic declared as wchar works whereas Non-wchar makes controller TimeOut
    `{
 wchar_t Tx[12];
 Byte Rx[12];
 Tx[0]='S'; Tx[1]=0xd;
 DWORD dwhandled;
 if (hCommPort != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
 { pin_ptr<wchar_t> pTx = &Tx[0];
  fSuccess = WriteFile(hCommPort, pTx, 4, &dwhandled, NULL);
  PurgeComm(hCommPort, PURGE_RXABORT|PURGE_TXABORT|PURGE_RXCLEAR|PURGE_TXCLEAR);
 pin_ptr<Byte> pRx = &Rx[0];
 fSuccess = ReadFile(hCommPort, pRx, 10, &dwhandled, NULL);
 }`

Comment: Did you try fixed-size types? `std::uint8_t`, `std::uint16_t`?

Comment: Well, microcontroller code was always uint8_t. Modifying the TxMessage<wchar> to TxMessage<std::uint8_t> in WinXP app does **NOT** help. Behavior is same as Non-wchar instances above. Micro-controller receives TWO bytes, first one correctly as 0x53 followed by second wrong byte as 0xC3. Further, RxMessage<std::uint8_t> too receives **Junk**, as Non-wchar instances above

Comment: This got to be some MS internal handling of WriteFile/ReadFile function parameters, where LPVOID lpBuffer works for wchar_t only. Can we have implementation details of WriteFile/ReadFile. Would it help if I share Source+Disassembly dump of writefile from VS2010 debug stepping

Comment: As I said before, just use raw C++ static array with fixed-size types without anything else, like `pin_ptr<wchar_t>`. And just write and read from PC end, do not use controller - let PC right and then read what it wrote to the port. And see what happens.

Comment: For Code below, w/o controller, two observations. **Observation #1** With BreakPoints at Write,Purge & Read; **Read waits to Timeout & Rx remains all 'Z'**.     `{std::uint8_t Tx[12]={'A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J','K','L'};
std::uint8_t Rx[12]={'Z','Z','Z','Z','Z','Z','Z','Z','Z','Z','Z','Z'};
DWORD dwhandled;
if (hCommPort != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE){
fSuccess = WriteFile(hCommPort, &Tx, 10, &dwhandled, NULL);
fSuccess = PurgeComm(hCommPort, PURGE_RXABORT|PURGE_TXABORT|PURGE_RXCLEAR|PURGE_TXCLEAR);
fSuccess = ReadFile(hCommPort, &Rx, 10, &dwhandled, NULL);}`

Comment: **Observation #2** With BreakPoints at Write & Read only; Read returns immediately without Timeout. Post Read, Rx holds random of two possibilities below on successive run-attempts:    `{'C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J','Z','Z','Z','Z'}` **OR**    `{'A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J','Z','Z'}` . Further, fsuccess returns 0x1 for all Write,Purge & Read

Comment: So, you write to port, then you purge it and then you read it? Can you comment out purging and test it without it? I would do it myself, but I don't have Windows on this machine...

Comment: Please note that, with micro-controller connected and BreakPoints at Write & Read only; Read returns either on receipt of 10 bytes on COM15 or after Timeout only. Timeouts = 10 seconds

Comment: Originally Purge was not implemented. In absence of Purge, Read used to return without Timeout(as if Tx echo acted on behalf of micro-controller). Thus Purging was introduced to be able to click run in WinXP and then switch to Micro-controller IDE to click run for Tx part. Effectively, debug scheme is micro-controller waits 8 secs for Tx from PC and PC waits 10 secs for Tx from Micro-controller to facilitate stepping in two different IDEs on need basis debugging

Comment: I would suggest removing `PurgeComm` and setting breakpoint on `ReadFile` on both PC end and controller's end. So, you `WriteFile` on PC end and it breaks on `ReadFile` there. You go to controller side, `ReadFile` there, then `WriteFile` there. Then you go back to PC end and `ReadFile`. However, this is very dirty, you need some kind of interprocess synchronization. Or use two ports - one to write from PC and read by controller, another - to write from controller and read by PC.

Comment: Effectivly,**A. PC to Micro::** click RUN in Micro-IDE at    `MicroRead` with timeout provision, say 8 secs;click RUN in VS2010 at    'PC_Write` and PC breaks on    `PC_Read`;      `MicroRead` will break to    'MicroWrite` either on receipt of 0xd or Timeout;    **B. Micro to PC::** click RUN in VS2010 at    `PC_Read` with timeout provision say 10 secs; switch to Micro-IDE and click RUN for Micro at    `MicroWrite`. **Since** without    `PurgeComm` the     `PC_Read` does **NOT** honor Timeout at all. so     `PC_Read` exits before one could switch to Micro-IDE and click RUN for     `MicroWrite`

Comment: You can write first and break right after at one end, then resume and read at the other end. Why do you need the timeout? The data should remain in the port buffer after your wrote there as long as any open handles to it exist in the system, right?

Comment: Ah, it seems our communication gap is that I'm debugging both PC-app and Micro firmware on single laptop, whereas you might be assuming them as two seperate systems. Timeout honors are needed at both ends, PC as well as Micro, for user to switch between PC IDE and Micro IDE(GUIs for runtime debugging) on single laptop. So that, clicking in one IDE window makes it wait to receive bytes from other IDE window, while user restores the other IDE window to transmit the bytes expected in former IDE.

Comment: It's like talking on phone. If I don't wait with earphones attached I will miss what you might have spoken recently

Comment: I think, it's not exactly like a phone. It's more like a drop-box. You drop something into it and until I (or someone else, probably, you yourself) takes it out - it will remain there. That's the point. So I suggest you write to port then break before reading on PC end, then switch to controller's IDE and resume so it will read from the port. Between writing and reading you can go have coffee - the port buffer should keep the data.

Comment: Well, port buffer would keep data **BUT** in serial comms, two devices don't access buffer of other device. Rather they just wait for characters to show up their ear-phone in real time ! once received, data can be preserved in recipient device buffer. I am pretty sure serial comms is synonomous to talking on phone only !

Comment: some success with changes to INTR handeling in micro. Now, sending "ABCDEFGHIJ" from micro is received perfectly in order with code below (**provided we have Breakpoint at PurgeComm**)    `for(int i=0;i<10;i++){
        fSuccess = ReadFile(hCommPort, &Rx[i], 1, &dwhandled, NULL); PurgeComm(hCommPort, PURGE_RXABORT|PURGE_TXABORT|PURGE_RXCLEAR|PURGE_TXCLEAR);}`  **Without Breakpoint** it receives alternates bytes as 0xFF e.g. 0x41 0xFF 0x42 0xFF 0x43 0xFF 0x44 0xFF ... where PurgeComm has been verified of returning success

Comment: synchronized as part of protocol that micro responds to commands from WinXP only and never transmots on its own

Comment: By the way, using FT_* functions from FTR232R e.g. FT_Read etc, in place of MS ReadFile are meeting expectation i.e. "ABCDEFGHIJ" received as "ABCDEFGHIJ". The only issue being moving declaration **FT_HANDLE fthandle;** from local function body to winform class throws compile error that managed and non-managed being mixed. Any code example to move this would solve the issue for time being

Answer (score 1):

Using bytes is the natural match, serial ports are pretty fundamentally byte oriented devices.  You could make your transmitting code look like this:

```
bool SendCommand(HANDLE hCommPort) {
    auto TxMessage = gcnew array<Byte> { 'S', '\r' };
    pin_ptr<Byte> pbytes = &TxMessage[0];
    DWORD bytesSent = 0;
    BOOL fSuccess = WriteFile(hCommPort, pbytes, TxMessage->Length, 
                              &bytesSent, NULL);
    return fSuccess && bytesSent == TxMessage->Length);
}
```

Your receiving code needs to do more work, the number of bytes you get back from ReadFile() is unpredictable.  A protocol is required to indicate when you should stop reading.  A fixed length response is common.  Or a special last character is very common.  That could look like this:

```
bool ReceiveResponse(HANDLE hCommPort, array<Byte>^ RxMessage, int% RxCount) {
    for (; RxCount < RxMessage->Length; ) {
        DWORD bytesReceived = 0;
        pin_ptr<Byte> pbytes = &RxMessage[0];
        BOOL fSuccess = ReadFile(hCommPort, pbytes, RxMessage->Length - RxCount, 
                                 &bytesReceived, NULL);
        if (!fSuccess) return false;
        int rxStart = RxCount;
        RxCount += bytesReceived;
        for (int ix = rxStart; ix < RxCount; ++ix) {
            if (RxMessage[ix] == '\r') return true;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Don't overlook the .NET System::IO::Ports::SerialPort class.  It has built-in Encoding support which makes it easier to work with characters vs bytes.  Your ReceiveResponse() method could collapse to a simple ReadLine() call with the NewLine property set correctly.

Comment: Appreciate your kind help. Unfortunetly, replacing wchar_t with Byte in WriteFile-part-of-code does **NOT** alter the run-time behavior of WriteFile. Still, micro-controller receives the two characters correctly as 0x53 followed by 0xD, only when TxMessage is declared as wchar_t. Non-wchar types (char, unsigned char, Byte etc.) make the  micro-controller receives the First byte correctly as 0x53 but 2nd byte wrong as 0x43 or 0xC3. The second character remains consistent as 0x43 or 0xC3 depending on choice of non-wchar_t to TxMessage array. Pls refer my answer to Petr below too

Comment: Dear Hans Any advice from your end! Hope you are following the discussion with Petr above.